# SQL Server 2008 R2 intellisense doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, ssms

The SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio intellisense stopped working a month ago though it is enabled. I read that this issue may be caused by the .NET framework 4.0 SP1 and tried some of the suggestions but nothing worked:

- I have installed the cumulative update package: `SQLServer2008R2_RTM_CU7_2507770_10_50_1777_x64`
- I re-registered the `TextMgrP.dll`

Any other suggestions what can be done?

The SSMS version is: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1617.0

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you are connected to SQL Server 2008 Edition. IntelliSense does not work with the previous versions of SQL Server.
2. IntelliSense should be enabled. There are two ways to verify whether IntelliSense is enabled or not. a) From Toolbar b) Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense
3. IntelliSense should be refreshed with the latest changes in database. a) Press CTRL+SHIFT+R b) Go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
4. Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> General -> IntelliSense Select Auto List Members and Check Parameter Information.

Comment: I am connected to the SQL Server 2008 Editiona and I had intellisense before a month or so. All options show that intellisense should work and I refreshed the cache many times.

Comment: I remember this bug, it lost intellisense randomly.  Basically I think it tries to load it and the intellisense indexing process is not very high priority.  So if for some reason it doesn't complete, you're stuck without it until it's able to finish.  Nothing I tried helped it finish at the time, that's why I'm not answering the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
For me the only thing it works was to select the database manually from the source code.

I just add

```
use MYDATABASE;
GO
```

Im my case it looks like that the source code couldn't be associated to a default database.