# IntelliSense is not working in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

We use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. IntelliSense works with SA account perfectly. But it is not working with Windows Authentication user. The user has access master db with db_owner role but it's not sysadmin.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can try solution from these [questions1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552458/4275342) or [questions2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20379681/4275342) and [questions3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13270249/4275342).

Or please try these steps as below:

- Enable IntelliSense:

  - For all query windows, please go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> IntelliSense, and select Enable IntelliSense.
  - For each opening query window, please go to Query >> Intellisense  Enabled.
- Enable statement completion: please go to Tools >> Options >> Text
  Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General, and check on Auto list members and
  Parameter information boxes.
- Refresh IntelliSense local cache: please go to >> Edit >>
  IntelliSense >>Refresh Local Cache or use the <kbd>CTRL+Shift+R</kbd> keyboard
  shortcut to refresh.
- Wait a minute or two for the Refresh to finish before trying again.

Comment: not working again. Everything is fine when loged in as SA. But other user(not sysadmin) cant use this feature.

Comment: also, ensure you are connected! I didn't manage intellisense to work, because took a yesterday launched query window, and MSSMS was already disconnected. Once reconnected the intellisense worked! )

Comment: Finally I have intellisense again - Enable statement completion was missing for me

Comment: cant believe i tried all suggestions on this page...and none works for me...wonder what's Microsoft doing about this issue for yearss

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue. Everything was enabled to ensure proper Intellisense functions, but didn't work. I realized I had SQLCMD mode enabled by default. Disabling it restored Intellisense functionality :)

Comment: I tried a million things before I stumbled upon this post. Really appreciate it. Intellisense worked on 2012 as soon as I unchecked sqlcmd.

Comment: Thx a lot. I was struggling with this for a day.

Comment: This was the fix for me as well. I found that I needed to turn it on - and then OFF again (2X? I don't remember now).

Comment: I had to turn SQLCMD mode off for all new queries (Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > General), then for some reason I needed to leave SSMS and go back in.  Yeah - I have my Intellisense back!

Comment: Much helpful to turn off sqlcmd!

Answer (score 26):

This may seem too short of an answer, but probably it's the solution to your Problem:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Also, I found this: 
[Troubleshooting IntelliSense (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173434.aspx)

Comment: Depending on the size and schema of the DB it can last several minutes until IntelliSense is populated

Comment: FYI, this is the keyboard shortcut for `Edit` > `IntelliSense` > `Refresh Local Cache`.  Some of the other options in that menu may help, if this doesn't (I just tried them all).

Answer (score 11):

Increasing the Maximum script size under Tools, Options, Text Editor, Transact-SQL, IntelliSense fixed Intellisense for me.

Comment: That got it working.  Strange.  I set Maximum Script Size to 2 MB from 1 MB.  Then I set back from 2MB back to original of 1MB and it's still working.  That's odd as you'd expect it to stop working.

Comment: Changing the Maximum script size fixed it for me too. Everything else was set correctly!

Answer (score 11):

I tried all the above/below suggestions... and nothing worked.

- Going to options and toggling everything off and on ***didn't work***.
- Toggling SQLCMD ***didn't work***
- Going to *Edit > Intellisense* and toggling everything off and on ***didn't work***.
- Changing RAM and Cache size ***didn't work***.
- I tried rebooting and that ***didn't work***.

But the one thing that finally (in an act of desparation where I'd try anything ... even the stupidest idea ever suggested...) that finally... **DID WORK** was:

I opened a new query tab.  Copied my code from the script file I had open, Pasted it into the new query tab. And proceeded to be stunned in horror as intellisense began working again.

Not only did it begin working in my new query tab... but it began working in my original one as well.

Sometimes I just want to bang my head againt the desk.

Hope this tid bit helps someone. :)

P.S. Yes... I waited a while after each of the failed attempts to make sure intellisense wasn't taking it's good ole time trying to find itself.  The "New Query Tab" insanity worked instantly.

Comment: To my amazement, this fixed the issue for me too.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this in 2 simple steps:

1. Go to **Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > IntelliSense**, tick everything and setup the settings this way:

[image]

2. Go to **Query > SQLCMD Mode**, and disable that:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Missing from other solutions, but fixed it for me:

```
Edit > IntelliSense > Toggle Completion Mode
```

or <kbd>CTRL+ALT+Space</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Although the option was already on, my intellisense did not work until the typical "turn it off and on again"...

Answer (score 6):

Turning **Query > SQLCMD Mode** on and off again fixed the issue for me in SSMS 18.1, even though it was never enabled to begin with.

After trying all the answers here to no avail and giving up, I remained curious about the **SQLCMD Mode** mentioned in Chow Lover's answer. I turned it on to see what it did, but noticed no change so turned it off again. Intellisense suddenly awoke and has been working fine since.

Answer (score 5):

My schemes were too big. I had to do this:

> Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> Intellisence
>
> **Maximum script size:** Unlimited

Answer (score 3):

**Disabling / re-enabling IntelliSense** worked for me:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > IntelliSense > Enable IntelliSense

Comment: What's crazy is that in SSMS2019, when I clicked this OFF, suddenly intellisense started working. Clicked it back on, still working. 

Amazing that version after version Microsoft can't get this simple concept right.

Comment: @LarryBud Yes, amazing. I have to do this regularly since years.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

My SSMS Intellisense was not working. Intellisense was Enabled from the Tools. Refreshed the Intellisense Local cache and still no luck.

**Solution:**

For me, the solution was to increase SQL Server [Minimum memory per query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-min-memory-per-query-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15)y (in KB). It was set to 1024 KB(1M). I increased it to 100 MB then it solved my problem.

**Disclaimer Notice:**

Please **do not** make this kind of changes without consulting your **DBA** and not knowing the resources available on that server. It basically, will allocate that amount of space for every new query window you will open. So, if you set too many users then you have low memory server and you set to something higher then your **server might crash**.

**Minimum memory per query settings:**

[image: Minimum memory per query settings:]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution at the end. I installed SQL2008 R2 SP3.

Answer (score 0):

It could also depends on your destination server.

For instance for server 2005, intellisense will not work.
Here is a command to check this :

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');
```

If version begin with **8 or 9** it will **not work**.

More information for  : [sql server intellisense trouble here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/)

A workaround could be to use a sql server plugin as [Autocomplete version express](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

After installing visual studio or upgrading that, this issue can happen follow the link :
[what is the problem of IntelliSense in sqI ntelliSense](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2531482/fix-the-intellisense-feature-in-ssms-2008-r2-may-stop-working-after-yo)
and for solve that you can do this: 
[update sql server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2527041/archived-how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2008-r2)
by updating to the latest version you can get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

- if Auto list members and Parameter information boxes are ENABLE, make them disable and then  press ok button. After the operation, make the boxes enable again and press ok button.
- if Auto list members and Parameter information boxes are DISABLE, make them enable and then  press ok button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have are seeing your text in red color, and have a bunch of statements, it could be because of a missing quote. Or a bad syntax check. Try typing a quote at the end. Then Intellisense should kick in again in your next statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me almost every time when intellisense goes off.  I go to the top of the query that I'm working on, and type:

```
Use DatabaseName; 
go
```

in SQL Server Management Studio, highlight it, and hit F5 (replace name of database with whichever one you are working on right now). When that has actioned, press Ctrl-shift-R, and then wait for around 30 seconds (maximum should be 2 mins). Intellisense should restart and make intelligent suggestions once again (assuming you are in the same query window as your F5 kick above).

You're welcome, mine is a pint of cider.

Answer (score 0):

Something else that I'd like to add, when all of the above responses don't fix the issue. I've noticed in SSMS that if there is a syntax error that intellisense sometimes doesn't work.

A quick /* */ around the block of code will usually take care of it.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a problem with one particular database.  Other databases on the same instance were fine.   I tried refreshing local cache (Ctrl+Shift+R) and disabling and enabling IntelliSense via Tools --> Options, but enabling and then disabling SQLCMD Mode **appeared** to do the trick for me.  Perhaps it was a combination of these things.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when updated SQL Server
If you turn off SQLCMD mode
Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server >General-> Uncheck(By default, open queries in SQLCMD mode) and its started working for me
[image]

[image]