# Autocomplete stopped working on SSMS 2016

Tags: sql-server, autocomplete, intellisense

**Autocomplete stopped working** some while ago for me. Intellisense seems to be otherwise working.

I tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580885/intellisense-is-not-working-at-sql-server-management-studio):

- Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> IntelliSense, and
  Enable IntelliSense is selected
- Refreshed IntelliSense local cache: both Edit >> IntelliSense >> Refresh Local Cache or the CTRL+Shift+R keyboard shortcut to refresh
- Enabled statement completion: please go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General, and checked on Auto list members and Parameter information boxes
- Rebooted SQL Server Management Studio several times
- Checked that shortcut "CTRL+Space" is enabled for "Edit.CompleteWord" in Text Editor in Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Keyboard

I have problem only with option:

- For each opening query window, please go to Query >> Intellisense Enabled

which is greyed out all the time:

[image]

I do not know, whether it is connected to my issue, but it might be.

**So, how do I enable Autocomplete again?**

Comment: Try restarting your ssms, and if that doesn't work, restarting your computer. Sometimes that's all you can do.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: After trying all the above, I eventually the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279972/979174

Comment: "Auto list members" was off for me. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

it worked for me after pressing Alt+(Right Arrow)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to forget about this issue and install 17.1 instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms. It is stable, free, looks beautiful and has more nice features than 2016.

Comment: IntelliSense stopped working in 17.1 (build 13.0.4435.0). However, it worked previously.

Comment: I am using 17.6 still IntelliSense not working on my machine

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem: I did all the above mentioned. Solved it finally by disabling the SQLCMD Mode (which was activated)!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My issue was solved by: Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache

Comment: This is the only answer the fixed it. All of this happened in the first place since I had opened one server, but I had also opened a query for another server. When I then connected to the needed server, Intellisense did not find the tables that were in the "Synonyms" folder. Refreshing the Intellisense Local Cache got rid of the red underlinings and missing auto-completion, but they come back at any change, as soon as I type something, draw something from the Object Explorer to the query window or run a query. Still better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the suggested solutions but nothing worked then I realized it didn't effect the query windows that was currently open.

**Simply opening a new query window solved it.**

Answer (score 0):

IntelliSense stopped working for me, due to offline databases. After bringing them online again, IntelliSense worked again.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS version 18.12.1

I found that Intellisense was failing on an existing large SQL query window with many lines of different queries contained within.

I took the suggestion from Rikard Askelöf of opening up a NEW query window, and Intellisense started working to auto complete the table names after I put a DOT after the schema name in a new query line.

I finally found the problem was caused by this:
My large original query window had some "errors" in it from me pasting row data, and not commenting it out. I'm guessing Intellisense was getting so confused it just gave up.

Once I went through my query window and commented out all of the lines that had RED error's indicated by the scrollbar on the right, Intellisense works once again.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Linked Server Credentials

There is one additional case that I have seen.  Took quite a bit of trouble to diagnose!

If the Server has a linked server and the credentials are no longer valid.

Autocompletion on objects freezes the cursor for a few seconds, then control comes back with no objects listed.

Comment: I have these red underlinings with a linked server as well, coming up at any new change in the query, for example, if I just type something, or if I draw another table from the Object Explorer to the query, or if I run the query. My credentials work, I run the query against "Synonyms" tables. I can refresh the intellisense cache to get rid of the red underlinings. Even though I have to do it again and again, this is better than nothing. See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68637540/11154841).

Answer (score -1):

My issue was solved by: Edit -> Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode