# Invalid Column Name issue with SSMS 18

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, intellisense, sql-server-2019

I just installed SQL Server 2019 Express, and SSMS (18.9). I also downloaded the AdventureWorksDW2019 Database from Microsoft. I successfully set up my connection.

**I've already tried doing this ->**
Enable IntelliSense:
For all query windows, please go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> IntelliSense, and select Enable IntelliSense.
For each opening query window, please go to Query >> IntelliSense Enabled.
Enable statement completion: please go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL >> General, and check on Auto list members and Parameter information boxes.
Refresh IntelliSense local cache: please go to >> Edit >> IntelliSense >>Refresh Local Cache or use the CTRL+Shift+R keyboard shortcut to refresh.
Wait a minute or two for the Refresh to finish before trying again.

**The Issue:** I am able to select a table, right-click and 'Select Top 1000 Rows' and the query runs fine, displaying the results as expected. However, for some reason, each column is underlined red stating 'Invalid column name'.

Because of this, I am unable to use IntelliSense when writing my own queries. I have checked that the correct IntelliSense settings are checked.

See screenshots below:

[Right-click -> 'Select Top 1000' works, but still no IntelliSense and same red underline 'Invalid Column Name'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCaQ5.png)

[Manually wrote own query, results show as expected, but still no IntelliSense and same red underline 'Invalid Column Name'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1S8F.png)

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (1000) [DateKey]
  ,[FullDateAlternateKey]
  ,[DayNumberOfWeek]
  ,[EnglishDayNameOfWeek]
  ,[SpanishDayNameOfWeek]
  ,[FrenchDayNameOfWeek]
  ,[DayNumberOfMonth]
  ,[DayNumberOfYear]
  ,[WeekNumberOfYear]
  ,[EnglishMonthName]
  ,[SpanishMonthName]
  ,[FrenchMonthName]
  ,[MonthNumberOfYear]
  ,[CalendarQuarter]
  ,[CalendarYear]
  ,[CalendarSemester]
  ,[FiscalQuarter]
  ,[FiscalYear]
  ,[FiscalSemester]
FROM [AdventureWorksDW2019].[dbo].[DimDate]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580885/intellisense-is-not-working-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: I'm still getting this intellisense error at 19.1.  Refreshing cache, restarting app does not fix.

Comment: SSMS 19.1 intellisense is not working properly(it starts and stops working randomly). Do not upgrade to this version. But if you are reading this then probably its too late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with SSMS 18.9, and a hotfix is currently being developed.

https://twitter.com/SysAdminDrew/status/1382869366702624774?s=20

[image: A tweet from Drew Skwiers-Koballa @SysAdminDrew explaining the issue and the upcoming hotfix.]